# Error with integrating FB SDK (Version 4.7.0) with iOS 9 in XCode 7.0.1: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, sdk

I follow the latest instruction at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) for integrating FBSDK (Version 4.7.0 downloaded) with my latest XCode. I am pretty sure I have configured the following in info.plist (I only need these for Version **4.7.0**):

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

and copied everything as Facebook provided in my Facebook Development account. However, when I tried to login with the Facebook Login Button, I got this error:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

When I see this error, my app just stuck and does not seem to have been authenticated even if I have clicked 'OK' in Safari. I also saw the following as explained by Facebook, but it doesn't make sense to me, as my app remains stuck with this error message.

```
In iOS 9, the app switches can prompt the user with a confirmation dialog. The SDK will try to minimize the frequency of this by choosing the best dialog available (such as SafariViewController), but this is by design in iOS 9.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound silly, but I found the solution, which is not related to the settings in my `.plist` file. I put the two following functions in my App Delegate, everything works correctly despite of the above warning for **fbauth2**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        // return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, session:PFFacebookUtils.session())
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)

    }



    //Make sure it isn't already declared in the app delegate (possible redefinition of func error)
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }
```